# param value with different passing mechanism

Tags: c++, pass-by-reference, pass-by-value

```
int f(float i, float j, float k)
{
  float x=i;
  i=j;
  j=k;
  k=x;}

main(){
  float x=5; y=10 z=25;
  if(...){
     f(x,y,z);
  }
  else{
     f(y,z,y); /* what's x,y,z after this line using call-by-reference and call-by-name mechanism*/
  }
 }
```

I think I have a pretty good understand about these three passing mechanism.

After f(x,y,z). x,y,z will have value

10 25 5 if it is call by reference

5 10 25 if it is call by value

10 25 5 if it is call by value result.

(I double checked answer, I am sure those are corrent)

but my answer is completely wrong for f(y,z,y). I got 10,25,10 for call by reference and call by name. How would value of x,y,z change after f(y,z,y) if it is using call by reference and call by name

Comment: the parameters of f are being passed by value in this example.

Comment: I'm not sure there is a call-by-value-result mechanism in C++. How did you check ?

Comment: I made some modification. This is a question from my exam. so I am just assuming those passing mechanism exist and see how param will change based on different passing mechanism

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for the "call by reference" for `f(y,z,y)`, first let us rewrite the code of the f function

```
int f(float & i, float & j, float & k)
{
   float t=i;
   i=j;
   j=k;
   k=t;
 }
```

(I renamed the local variable `x` to `t` to avoid confusions)

Calling `f(y,z,y)` amounts to the following sequence:

```
 {
  float t=y;
   y=z;
   z=y;
   y=t;
 }
```

with the initial values y=10 z=25, so

```
   float t=10;
   y=25;
   z=25;
   y=10;
```

ending with z=25, y=10 and x unchanged.

Comment: Thank you so much. I just realized I wrote my answer as value of y,z,y instead of x,y,z.